# How to make this Razor View work like the ASPX one does?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have been struggling to get a partial View working in Razor. The View engine cannot make sense of the code below but it is simple using the ASPX View engine. Can anyone show me how to get this to work with Razor? Note that I am just writing out a calendar so the <tr> tag happens at the end of every week. The first sign of a problem is that the Razor code will not format in the VS editor and it complains that the 'while' block is missing its closing brace. I have tried all kinds of combinations, even using a delegate. (I think the cause of the problem may be the conditional TR tag because it is highlighted as an error because it is not closed.)

**Razor (doesn't work)**

```
 <table class="calendarGrid">
    <tr class="calendarDayNames">
        <th>Monday</th>
        <th>Tuesday</th>
        <th>Wednesday</th>
        <th>Thursday</th>
        <th>Friday</th>
        <th>Saturday</th>
        <th>Sunday</th>
    </tr>
    @{
        var loopDate = gridStartDate;
    }
    @while (loopDate <= gridEndDate)
    {
        if (loopDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday)
        {
            <tr class="calendarWeek">
        }
            <td class="calendarDay">
                <span class="calendarDayNumber">@loopDate.Day</span>
                @if (Model.AllCalendarDays.ContainsKey(loopDate.Date))
                {
                    foreach (var ev in Model.AllCalendarDays[loopDate.Date])
                    {
                        <span class="calendarEvent">@ev.Venue</span>
                    }
                }
            </td>
            @{ 
                loopDate = loopDate.AddDays(1);
                @if (loopDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday)
                {
                    </tr>
                }
            }
    }
```

**ASPX (works)**

```
  <table class="calendarGrid">
    <tr class="calendarDayNames">
        <th>Monday</th>
        <th>Tuesday</th>
        <th>Wednesday</th>
        <th>Thursday</th>
        <th>Friday</th>
        <th>Saturday</th>
        <th>Sunday</th>
    </tr>
    <% 
        var loopDate = gridStartDate;

        while (loopDate <= gridEndDate)
        {
            if (loopDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday)
            {
    %>
    <tr class="calendarWeek">
        <%} %>
        <td class="calendarDay">
            <span class="calendarDayNumber">
                <%: loopDate.Day %></span>
            <% if (Model.AllCalendarDays.ContainsKey(loopDate.Date))
               {
                   foreach (var ev in Model.AllCalendarDays[loopDate.Date])
                   { %>
            <span class="calendarEvent">
                <%: ev.Venue %></span>
            <%  }
               } %>
        </td>
        <%  {
                loopDate = loopDate.AddDays(1);
                if (loopDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday)
                { %>
    </tr>
    <% }
            }
        } %>
</table>
```

**Working solution in Razor based on @jgauffin's view model suggestion and @dommer's ugly raw html solution. Combined together they're almost aesthetically acceptable. :)**

**View model now has iterator**

```
    public IEnumerable<Tuple<DateTime, IList<CalendarEventDto>>> GridItems()
    {
        var loopDate = GridStartDate;
        while (loopDate <= GridEndDate)
        {
            yield return new Tuple<DateTime, IList<CalendarEventDto>>(loopDate.Date, AllCalendarDays[loopDate.Date]);
            loopDate = loopDate.AddDays(1);
        }
    }
```

Okay, the Tuple is lazy but I will probably create another model to hold more complex information about the date and events (IsPast/greyed, etc).

**The pesky View**

```
           @foreach (var item in Model.GridItems())
        {
            if (item.Item1.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday)
            { 
                @Html.Raw("<tr class=\"calendarWeek\">");
            }
            @Html.Raw("<td class=\"calendarDay\">");
            @Html.Raw(string.Format("<span class=\"calendarDayNumber\">{0}</span>", item.Item1.Day));
            foreach (var ev in item.Item2)
            {
                @Html.Raw(string.Format("<span class=\"calendarEvent\">{0}</span>", Server.HtmlEncode(ev.Venue)));
            }
            @Html.Raw("</td>");
            if (item.Item1.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
            {
                @Html.Raw("</tr>");
            }
        }
```

Note that when I reformat the View source in VS, it gets egregiously tabbed, with the if statement having about 10 tabs to the left of it, but there are no compilation warnings and it does what I want. Not nice, or easy though. I think the Razor devs should provide some support for explicit breakout and breakin to code and markup so that when the parser cannot parse it unambiguously, we can tell it what we intended.

**@Andrew Nurse's solution**
Andrew 'works on the ASP.Net team building the Razor parser!'. His solution runs okay but still produces compiler warnings and is obviously confusing Visual Studio because the code cannot be reformatted without ending up in a big glob on a few lines:

```
       <tbody>
        @foreach (var calDay in Model.GridItems())
        {
            if (calDay.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday)
            { 
                @:<tr class="calendarWeek">
            } 
            <td class="calendarDay">
                <span class="calendarDayNumber">@calDay.Day</span> 
                @foreach (var ev in calDay.CalendarEvents) 
                { 
                    <span class="calendarEvent">@ev.Venue</span> 
                } 
            </td> 
            if (calDay.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
            { 
                @:</tr>                 
            }
        }
    </tbody>
```

Comment: What kind of error do you get? Also: I would move the logic into the viewmodel to make it testable.

Comment: The error is that firstly it doesn't format (I get compile warnings), and if I run it, depending on how I change the blocks, I either get nothing at all omitted or an 'out of memory' exception because the loop variable incrementor is not being executed. I think my general point is that something which is very easy and predictable in ASPX is almost impossible to fathom in Razor :)

Comment: Depending on how I change it, I get Razor compilation errors such as: 'TR has no closing tag', 'if block does not need opening @ when code block', 'missing closing brace on 'while' block. And if I fix all that and get it to compile, all of the 'if block' code is emitted as raw text, which the browser causes to be shown above the table.

Comment: I have given up on this problem for now since I have lost too much time on it. The ASPX version works fine. The parsing seems to go awry in the opening if block with the <tr> tag. I have tried wrapping it in text tags etc but nothing works. I think that rendering the rows using a partial would work but why should you need to?

Comment: I have had one last try. I'd be interested to know what sort of output it produces if you wouldn't mind trying it.

Comment: Your last solution below worked.

Comment: I've updated my question code with the syncretic solution based on your various suggestions. Thanks for your help. If anyone can now get rid of the Html.Raw, I'll be even more happier.

Comment: I've updated my question code to show Andrew Nurse's solution. This issue reminds me of the comments by the developers of System.IO who were stunned when 8 out of 8 'average' developers in usability tests were unable to read a text file after 30 minutes (see 'Framework Design Guidelines', pp 17-18). It was too late to change the lib. If something so simple is so difficult to achieve, it is a bad smell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The primary issues here were these lines:

```
if (loopDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday)
{
    <tr class="calendarWeek">
}

...

@if (loopDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday)
{
    </tr>
}
```

The problem is that Razor uses the tags to detect the start and end of markup. So since you didn't close the "tr" tag inside the first if, it doesn't actually switch back to code, so it doesn't see the "}" as code. The solution is to use "@:", which lets you put a line of markup without regard for tags. So replacing those lines with this should work and be more concise than using Html.Raw:

```
if (loopDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday)
{
    @:<tr class="calendarWeek">
}

...

@if (loopDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday)
{
    @:</tr>
}
```

Comment: Although your solution runs okay, the compiler and VS editor are still reporting it as erroneous (I have pasted your solution into my question above). I get compiler warnings about text not being allowed between tbody and tr tags. The warnings are visually highlighted in the editor and I cannot reformat the document because all of the code ends up wrapped into 6 lines instead of about 15. It is revealing that five experienced MVC developers, including one of the Razor team developers, have failed to satisfactorily solve this simple problem after multiple attempts.

Comment: +1 I didn't know about `@:`. Is `@:` just shorthand for `@Html.Raw(`...`)`?

Comment: @Dommer Kinda, but I'd think of it as just a simple directive to say: Everything from here to end-of-line is markup. Unlike Html.Raw, you can actually still use "@" expressions, etc. inside the line you're outputting with "@:"

Comment: @Rob - I took a look at how VS formats the code and you're definitely right there's a glitch there. The editor is a separate team so I'll raise the issue with them and see if we can get it fixed in the next version. No promises, but I'll take the feedback directly to the editor team.

Comment: Thanks for the info Andrew, I didn't know about using `@:` and it's cool that you're going to pass on the issue that Rob has identified. A result all round - except I lost 15 points by having my correct answer taken away... :-D

Comment: @Dommer Yes, sorry about that. It was a tough decision but I think that Andrew's answer was the best eventually. Although yours worked as well so there should be some way to choose both :)

Comment: @Andrew. Yes, I can see that the compiler/parser is working correctly but the VS editor is not. Also, if I reformat my code and it gets all wrapped up together, it then fails to compile, so I assume that the parser is treating line-endings as significant as well. Because Razor is implicit (not explicit like ASPX), you may have to include some fallback syntax to explicitly mark code and markup, at least to keep VS happy, in the same way that we use /// <reference> for JS intellisense.

Comment: The idea is that @: and <text> should be that fallback syntax. Unfortunately it seems that the editor is breaking that. That's definitely NOT supposed to happen, so I hope we can fix it, but at the worst, you can use the Html.Raw calls from Dommer's answer just for the <tr> tags.

Comment: I decided to use your version but it does break whenever I reformat, but now that I have got it down to about five lines, it doesn't really matter thanks (and I know when it breaks, because it tells me!).

Answer (score 1):

I would move all logic to the viewmodel which leaves the following code in your view:

```
@while (Model.MoveNext())
{
    @Model.WeekHeader
        <td class="calendarDay">
            <span class="calendarDayNumber">@Model.DayNumber</span>
            @foreach (var ev in Model.CurrentDayEvents)
            {
                <span class="calendarEvent">@ev.Venue</span>
            }
        </td>
    @Model.WeekFooter
}
```

And the new model:

```
public class CalendarViewModel
{
    private DateTime _currentDate;

    public string WeekHeader
    {
        get
        {
            return _currentDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday ? "<tr class="calendarWeek">" : "";
        }
    }
    public string WeekFooter
    {
        get
        {
            return _currentDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday ? "</tr>" : "";
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<DayEvent> 
    { 
        get 
        { 
            return AllCalendarDays.ContainsKey(loopDate.Date) ? AllCalendarDays[loopDate.Date] ? new List<DayEvent>();
        }
    }

public bool MoveNext()
{
    if (_currentDate == DateTime.MinValue)
    {
        _currentDate = gridStartDate;
        return true;
    }

    _currentDate = _currentDate.AddDays(1);
    return _currentDate <= gridEndDate;
}
}
```

Comment: That's interesting, but I don't think View code (HTML) should be in a view model. Also, I don't think it solves the problem that the html is now invalid because there is no TR in the view, which is what seems to be causing the issue.

Comment: Another thing is that I have the same model for a weekly, monthly or yearly calendar, which is just  start and end date, with a list of events in that period. The View layout of the tables varies according to the duration of the calendar.

Comment: ViewModels was made to remove logic from the views. you don't get a <tr> unless the startdate is a monday

Comment: Remove the logic from the View, but not put the View in the ViewModel :) - separation of concerns. I like your MoveNext idea though. However, the issue here is not about what should be in the View/ViewModel, it's the complexity of mixing code and html when using Razor and the vagaries of the interpretor. I wrote the ASPX version in 5 minutes and have lost 12 hours doing a Razor one which still doesn't work, no matter what variations I use. That means there is something fundamentally broken or overly-complicated with Razor, in my opinion.

Comment: razor works fine if yuo don't put too much logic in it :) Use `<text></text>` blocks around the html to tell razor that you switched from code to plain HTML

Comment: According to the documentation, text tags are only required if you are switching from code to plain text which isn't wrapped with an html element; that is, it tells it you are back into markup. Since I have <tr> tag, text doesn't help me.

Comment: I've updated my original question with a solution that incorporates your iterator idea, although I used 'yield' instead. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**MAJOR EDIT:** Okay, what happens if you do this?

```
<table class="calendarGrid">
<tr class="calendarDayNames">
    <th>Monday</th>
    <th>Tuesday</th>
    <th>Wednesday</th>
    <th>Thursday</th>
    <th>Friday</th>
    <th>Saturday</th>
    <th>Sunday</th>
</tr>
@{
var loopDate = gridStartDate;
while (loopDate <= gridEndDate)
{
    if (loopDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday)
    {
        @Html.Raw("<tr class=\"calendarWeek\">");
    }
    @Html.Raw("<td class=\"calendarDay\">");
    @Html.Raw("<span class=\"calendarDayNumber\">" + loopDate.Day + "</span>");
    if (Model.AllCalendarDays.ContainsKey(loopDate.Date))
    {
        foreach (var ev in Model.AllCalendarDays[loopDate.Date])
        {
            @Html.Raw("<span class=\"calendarEvent\">" + ev.Venue + "</span>");
        }
    }
    @Html.Raw("</td>");
    loopDate = loopDate.AddDays(1);
    if (loopDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday)
    {
        @Html.Raw("</tr>");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I did try that variation but same problem. I'm sure it is the conditional TR elements causing the problem.

Comment: Ok, tried that. I get out of memory exception because the loop variable is not being incremented, which means it must be being seen as text.

Comment: Try ordinary parentheses around the incrementing bit, like in my edit. Or try `@loopDate = @loopDate.AddDays(1)`. I also don't think you need the semicolon do you? Again, I am away from VS2010, so I can't actually try this. Sorry.

Comment: Tried both of those. The problem seems to start further up with the opening TR. I can see that it cannot parse it because of what it gives me with intellisense, that is, it offers me html TR tags inside code blocks. I'm giving up on this problem now and going to do this one view in ASPX.

Comment: This is my last try! I have tried this in VS2010 at last and it looks like it should work (compiles okay), but I obviously haven't run it...

Comment: Funnily enough, Html.Raw was my first solution but it didn't emit anything into the response, and neither does yours. But it does if you put an @ in front of Html.Raw, otherwise the method's return string is not going anywhere. It needs '@Html.Raw(...'.

Okay, so this is uglier and more ungainly than using ASPX, in my opinion, but it does compile and work :) Thanks

Comment: PS For other readers, the first four comments are referring to an earlier solution, not the code there now, which does compile and work.

Comment: I have added the `@` symbols as per your suggestion. Thanks for trying it out and confirming it works. And yes, I agree it's not very elegant and perhaps a different solution would be better. But at least we made it work between us.

Comment: I've updated my original question with a solution that incorporates your code. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding `<text>` tags around the contents of the blocks?

[image: Alternatively, Razor also allows you to use a text element to explicitly identify content]

I think the Razor parse only works when it's obvious where the blocks end. It may be getting confused by the fact you have an if, a `td` and then some more code, all inside the block.

There's more info on this here: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/15/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-s-and-lt-text-gt-syntax.aspx

Comment: Thanks. I will try that and have seen the text element before. But I note this: "This makes it convenient when you want to render multi-line content blocks that are not wrapped by an HTML element." Since I am using html elements, that should not apply, but I will give it a go.

Comment: I think that description is over-simplified. I think it applies when the *entire content* is not wrapped in an HTML element.

Comment: Okay. Tried the text blocks but it then complains about missing end tags for the text. Seems that the TR is confusing up the interpreter.

Comment: Also, according to my 'Professional ASP MVC 3' book, the text tag is only used for plain text, not markup. I think all of my problems stem from the unclosed TR tag, because one of the warnings I get is, 'text not allowed inside TR tag', which proves that the closing brace } of that block is being treated as text.

Comment: The `<text>` tag spcifically lets you have tags that don't match up - that's really one of the main points, so you can do things like: if (blah) { <tr> }

Comment: You'll probably need several `<text>` blocks, like around the </tr> in ` @if (loopDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday)`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4224/discussion-between-rob-kent-and-danny-tuppeny)

Comment: Actually, the <text> tag does _not_ allow mismatched tags, but it often works for open tags, like this: <text><tr></text> because we see the end </text> as a "higher" tag in the stack and just ignore the unclosed <tr>. This would NOT work: <text></tr></text>. Mismatched tags are what @: is for.

Comment: Er, I was gonna say that next! ;-) Thanks for clarifying, I wasn't aware of that! :-)